Why does input type="time" display as radio button on iOS?
I have a time input field in my React app. Code:
      <div style={{ marginTop: '30px' }}>
    <input
      aria-label="Time"
      type="time" 
      onChange={handleTimeChange}
      style={{ padding: '8px', fontSize: '16px', width: 'auto' }}
    />
  </div>

Why on iOS it shows as radio buton? On dekstop it shows as expected as time input field. Using Safari on both devices.



I just checked and my iOS Safari displays a basic <input type="time"> reasonably well, so your question is really "why does my time input look this way", which means you a) need to share some more code, especially styles and b) might consider starting with the Safari debugger to see how it's styled.

Please check if the input type=time is supported in the browser version that you are using.

@ceejayoz thanks, i got some sleep and after double checking in safari debugger there should be some weird styling in my code. thanks for checking for me.

@rick its widely supported but some browsers fix css errors which took me by surprise. thanks for chiming in

@user1381985 I've found it "shocking" to read that the time input type was not embedded in Safari desktop until 2021.
